# Rails login and registration by facebook using 'omniauth-facebook' how get language , education , work and other of an users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, omniauth, registration

I use devise for the users and 'omniauth-facebook'
so in my user.rb i have write this function:

def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user

```
user = User.create(name: auth.extra.raw_info.first_name,
                   surname: auth.extra.raw_info.last_name,
                   provider: auth.provider,
                   uid: auth.uid,
                   email: auth.info.email,
                   password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20],
                   state: auth.extra.raw_info.locale.gsub(/_/, '-'),
                   gender: auth.extra.raw_info.gender,
                   language: auth.extra.raw_info.language,
                   bio: auth.extra.raw_info.bio,
                   work: auth.extra.raw_info.work || { },
                   education: auth.extra.raw_info.education

)
end
 user
end
```

everything works except  education and work
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook
Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'education' at row 1: INSERT INTO `users` (`address`, `bio`, `created_at`, `current_sign_in_at`, `current_sign_in_ip`, `education`, `email`

app/models/user.rb:23:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in`facebook'

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def facebook
  @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

  if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

end

while language remain empty !

You also know how to take address or other data thanks.

Comment: Looks like your education datatype is not correct... Wich datatype have you defined in your migration? .. try to use text instead of string if you used string for education

Comment: thanks :) so i don't understand why with some user return ---{}
while others for example all text:
---
- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  employer: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    id: '114770231873033'
    name: Ministero Pubblica Istruzione
  location: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    id: '107828345912209'
    name: Giarre
  description: insegnante
  start_date: 0000-00
  end_date: 0000-00

how catch only for example employer name or only descrpition?